# Dynamic caption for a section

Tags: linkki

How do I add a dynamic caption for a UI section, for example consider the following section:

```
@UISection(caption = "Persons")
```

The text 'Persons' is a static caption. How do I include the number of persons in the caption, e.g. 'Persons(5)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the annotation @BindCaption to specify a dynamic caption of the whole section as described in https://doc.linkki-framework.org/1.3.0/05_ui_components/04_additional_binding.html#bind-caption

linkki then calls the method `getCaption()` in your pmo. For example:

```
@UISection
@BindCaption
public class PersonSectionPmo {

public String getCaption() {
    return name;
}
```